# Why do I have to use the 'use' keyword on every class?

Tags: php, autoload

I am new to OOPHP and using frameworks. I successfully got all my custom classes to autoload using PSR-4 autoloading, but I have to use the `use` keyword constantly. This is probably a dumb question, but I really can't understand why autoloading is so useful if I have to `use` all my classes when I need them in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the "autoload PSR-4" is responsible for only providing your classes, so you can avoid writing a lot of manual "requires/includes" of your classes.

But, those same classes probably belong to specific namespaces and because that, to be able to "use" any of them, yes you have to write the "use" statement :-)

Also, the `use` statement has some interesting features, for example, you can alias a class. Another thought, every time you open a script file and read through all the "use" statement you can have a general idea about what classes/objects the script will deal with.

[You can read more about using namespaces here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment. It's starting to make more sense :).